# Diagonal line with fixed angle with curves in css

Tags: html, css

How would you draw a diagonal line, which always has an angle of 11° and fixed round corners on each end. It will be used as an overlay of an image such as the following example:

[image]

The gray area should be on top, and the blue would be the image.

And ideally stylable via either plain CSS or perhaps data:image/svg+xml as a background image.

Perhaps something similar to using either the `::after` selector on top of the image. Or perhaps even the `::before` selector on the content div that will be added to it. For example something similar to:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <p>Body copy</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .content:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your suggested solutions?

Comment: If you can use SVG is fine. But with CSS + HTML this will be hard to achieve because you need skew transforms and you will have problems with texts, etc. Are you trying with an image over the layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Each pseudo-element uses a combination of:

- `absolute positioning`
- `border`
- `border-radius`
- `box-shadow`
- `transform: skewY`:

```css
div {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 256px;
height: 140px;
margin-right:32px;
background: url('/my-image.jpg') no-repeat rgb(15,150,196);
overflow: hidden;
}

div::before, div::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
display: block;
width: calc(100% - 12px);
height: 100%;
border-width: 3px 6px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgb(178,178,178);
border-radius: 9px;
box-shadow: 36px -36px 0 36px rgb(178,178,178), -2px 2px 0 2px rgb(178,178,178);
transform: skewY(11deg);
}

div::before {
bottom: 50%;
}


div::after {
top: 50%;
box-shadow: -36px 36px 0 36px rgb(178,178,178), 2px -2px 0 2px rgb(178,178,178);
}

.with-image {
background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/115045/pexels-photo-115045.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb') no-repeat 0 0 / 256px 140px rgb(15,150,196);
}

.with-image::before, .with-image::after {
border-color: rgb(0,127,0);
box-shadow: 36px -36px 0 36px rgb(0,127,0), -2px 2px 0 2px rgb(0,127,0);
}

.with-image::after {
box-shadow: -36px 36px 0 36px rgb(0,127,0), 2px -2px 0 2px rgb(0,127,0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="with-image"></div>
```

Comment: That seems fine. Good job

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you to reach what you are trying to do.

```css
.container{
  width:300px; 
  margin-top:30px;
}
.imagecontainer{
  width:100%; 
  height:200px;
  background:blue;
  transform: skew(0deg, 11deg);
  border-radius:10px;
  margin-bottom:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagecontainer"></div>
  <div class="imagecontainer"></div>
  <div class="imagecontainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would also skew the image. I would imagine that this isn't what OP wants: https://jsfiddle.net/f5Lj3u8t/